# SQL Server query for inserting deleted row

Tags: sql-server-2008

What would be the SQL query to insert the deleted row from Table "A" into another table "B" ?

Comment: Yes.. I have created the trigger but error is coming as "Create Trigger must be the only statement in the batch". Can you give me the detailed explanation..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to include your CREATE TRIGGER code. Also, be aware that your error has nothing to do with your question!

Answer (score 3):

If `TableB` meets the requirements for tables that are [the target of an `OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx).

```
DELETE FROM TableA 
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO TableB 
WHERE Foo='Bar'
```

> **The following restrictions apply to the target of the outer INSERT
>   statement:**
>
> - The target cannot be a remote table, view, or common table
>     expression.
> - The target cannot have a FOREIGN KEY constraint, or be
>     referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
> - Triggers cannot be defined on
>     the target.
> - The target cannot participate in merge replication or
>     updatable subscriptions for transactional replication.

And if it doesn't meet these requirements a work around is

```
INSERT INTO TableB
EXEC('
DELETE FROM TableA 
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE Foo=''Bar''
')
```

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal - Thanks for the edit. I was feeling a bit lazy there!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CopyOnDelete
ON A
AFTER DELETE 
AS
    INSERT INTO B
    SELECT * FROM deleted
GO
```